# dependent classes as other class members

Tags: c++, constructor, initialization, operator-precedence, ctor-initializer

I have a class `B` that requires an instance of class `A` to be constructed:

```
class B
{
    B(A* a); // there is no default constructor
};
```

Now I want to create a class that contains `B` as a member, so I also need to add `A` as a member and provide it to `B`'s constructor:

```
class C
{
    C() : a(), b(&a) {}
    A a; // 1. initialized as a()
    B b; // 2. initialized as b(&a) - OK
};
```

But the problem is that if someone occasionally changes the order of the variables *definition* in the class, it will break

```
class C
{
    C() : a(), b(&a) {}
    B b; // 1. initialized as b(&a) while "a" uninitialized
    A a; // too late...
};
```

Is there a good way to resolve this without modifying the classes `A` and `B`? Thanks.

Comment: This is why you should always compile with all warnings turned on. All compilers emit a warning here if told to.

Comment: You may simply leave it as it is and add a giant warning as a comment. Also, consider enabling all the warnings, usually compilers provide a warning if the fields declaration order (which is the one that matters) is different from the order of the initializer list; if anyone by chance would swap the order of the two fields you'd get such warning.

Comment: @Alexandre C., @Matteo Italia: I've tried in MSVC and gcc (mingw 3.4.5) - no warning by default...

Comment: FWIW, g++ can give you a warning for this case if you compile at -Wall (I can't find the specific warning that triggers this).

Comment: g++ 4.4.5 gives such a warning with `-Wall`

Comment: @TimMartin: You can use -fdiagnostics-show-option to see which option controls any given diagnostic.

Comment: `without modifying the classes A and B` isn't this an indicator of bad style when `B` needs to use `A*` in the constructor? How realistic is this class `C` - how would you describe its function?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Is there a good way to resolve this without modifying the classes A and B?

Turn on [compiler warnings](http://codepad.org/xnQKPoiZ); for gcc, this is -Wreorder (which is included in -Wall):

```
cc1plus: warnings being treated as errors
t.cpp: In constructor 'A::A()':
Line 3: warning: 'A::y' will be initialized after
Line 3: warning:   'int A::x'
Line 2: warning:   when initialized here
```

Alternatively, use a lint-like tool that detects this.

---

> But the problem is that if someone occasionally changes the order of the variables definition in the class…

Why would they do this?  I suspect you're worrying too much about what *might* happen.  Even so, you can leave a comment in the class:

```
A a;  // Must be listed before member 'b'!
B b;
```

Don't underestimate the force of well-placed comments. :) Then allow someone who purposefully ignores them to get what they deserve; you are using C++, after all.

Comment: I'm not worrying as much as you say, I'm just curious. And I cannot turn on compiler warnings on every machine in the world :)

Comment: @7vies: If this is for your project, you should have some say over the compiler (and lint) options used.  Beyond that, I've learned that I can't fix everyone else, even if I had the time. :)

Answer (score 5):

Use the well-known C++ idiom called [Base-from-Member](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Base-from-Member) to solve this problem.

Define a base class as,

```
class C_Base
{
    A a; //moved `A a` to the base class!
    C_Base() : a() {}
};

class C : public C_Base
{
    C() : b(&a) {}
    B b; // 1. initialized as b(&a) while "a" uninitialized
    //A a; // too late...
};
```

Now, `a` is guaranteed to be initialized before `b`.

Comment: Isn't it weird to create a base class just to force the initialization order?

Comment: @7vies: Seems that way to me.  It is almost as if deterministic initialization order is useful...

Comment: @7vies: Yeah, but it's even wierder to think that someone would change the order of variables in class.

Comment: Base-from-member shouldn't be used where it isn't necessary: the complexity just isn't worth it.  It is required only if you have a "member" which you need to initialize before a base class.

Comment: @Fred: I agree! But if one fears that a particular member `a` must be initialized before `b`, then it may be useful.

Comment: I don't see how you can both agree and say it may be useful.  It's *easier* to make sure your members are declared in the right order than it is to use base-from-member.

Comment: @Fred: You think it's not useful?

Comment: Yes: if it shouldn't be used, then it's not useful.

Comment: @Fred: Useful and Overkill is not the same and one thing. Base-From-Member is overkill. That doesn't mean it's not useful.

Comment: The base from member idiom is the only *safe* way to enforce order of initialization. In a metaprogramming context it can be used just for this purpose. I agree though that in a specific inline context, just listing the members in the right order is the good solution.

Answer (score 2):

Store b in a unique_ptr, and set it in the body, not in the initializer list:

```
class C
{
    C() :a() {
        b = std::unique_ptr<B>(new B(&a));
    }
    A a;
    std::unique_ptr<B> b;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to not explicitly store the A, but instead to use dynamic allocation to create a new A to store in the B:

```
class C {
public:
       C() : b(new A) {
           // handled in initialization list
       }
private:
       B b;
};
```

Since this guarantees that the A is created before the B, this should prevent this problem from ever occurring.

Comment: Who is going to `delete A` then? I mean, you allocate memory with `new` but you cannot `delete` it, and `B` is not going to handle this.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are shooting yourself in the foot with the third example. In C++ the order of member variables in a class/struct matters. No matter how you go about solving your particular problem, if you pass uninitialized data to a constructor due to poor class design / member layout, you will be working with unitialized data and possibly get undefined behavior, depending on the sort of code in place.

To address your particular example, if `B` really requires an `A` and the relationship is one to one, why not create a new class `AB` that has both an `A` object and a `B` object in the right order and pass the address of `A` to `B`. That is:

```
class AB
{
public:
  AB():b_(&a_) {}

private:
  A a_;
  B b_;
};
```

now class `C` can avoid the ordering problem by using `AB` instead of `A` and `B`:

```
class C
{
public:
  ...
private:
  AB ab_;
};
```

As forementioned, this of course assumes a 1:1 relationship between `A` and `B`. If an `A` object can be shared by many `B` objects, things get more complicated.

Comment: The third example is here just to show why the second one is bad. I know that it is bad, my question is how to make it right.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how much control you have over the implementation and structure of C but is it necessary to use the objects themselves in class C? Could you redefine the class to use pointers instead and then move them from the initialization list, e.g.

```
class C
{
   C()
   {
     a = new A;
     b = new B(a);
   }
   ~C() {delete a; delete b;}

   A* a;
   B* b;
};
```

This avoids the issue of order in the declaration, but gives you the new issue of ensuring they're created correctly. Also, if you create **A LOT** of C's very often, an initialization list is slightly faster.

Comment: But then how do you protect from anyone reordering the lines in the constructor?  ;-)

Comment: @Bo Give up on programming and go ride bikes :P

Comment: @Bo Persson: Well, for me the difference between reordering lines in code (changing code) and reordering member definitions (e.g. during refactoring) is quite obvious, so I don't see your point.